# Keep users signed in when changing domain (Firebase Auth)

Tags: firebase, authentication, cookies, firebase-authentication, session-cookies

We are moving our app from `example.com` to `app.example.com`.

We have thousands of users signed in with **Firebase Auth**, and we'd like to keep them signed in when they open the new `app.example.com` subdomain. Is there any way to do this?